# If else inside a function - calling the function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
<script>
let car = CarFunction();

function CarFunction(lang) {

var carNo = (prompt("Enter Car No"));

if (carNo === '1') {
    return('Sedan');
   } else if (CarNo == '2') {
    alert('Truck');
} else {
    alert('No record found');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert(car)
</script>
```

I'm trying to call the function that I've created, where the number is taken from a user input, unfortunately it does not work. This method is the same I've used in other `function` I've created and it work...what is supposed to be the problem?

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: "it does not work" — This is not a clear problem statement. Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. **Read the error messages**. Stackoverflow is not here to crowdsource trivial typo errors where you didn't count your braces properly.

Comment: Use `return` instead of `alert` in your `CarFunction`.

Comment: Your fail is that CarNo == '2' not exists. You write CarNo and the var name is carNo

Comment: car is not defined in line 20 , what is car ? u define car in `<script>` but use it outside

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script>
let car = CarFunction();

function CarFunction(lang) {

var carNo = (prompt("Enter Car No"));

if (carNo === '1') {
        return('Sedan');
    }else if (carNo == '2') {
        return('Truck');
    } else {
        alert('No record found');
    }
}
alert(car)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert(car)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you just called the function outside the script just a small mistake hope the below code helps

```html
<head>
<script>
let car = CarFunction();

function CarFunction(lang) {

var carNo = (prompt("Enter Car No"));

if (carNo === '1') {
        return('Sedan');
    }else if (carNo == '2') {
        return('Truck');
    } else {
        alert('No record found');
    }
}
alert(car)
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```